# Як перекласти "бридость" з російської?

Tags: переклад, from-russian

Цікавить слово, якого навіть гугл не знає. Російська Вікіпедія містить статтю на слово "бридость". Власне, англіського аналогу також не знайшла.

[Бридость](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%91%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C) - (пер.мій) повна відсутність у тієї чи іншої особи кулінарного смаку, або тимчасова втрата чи викривлення смаку...

Українського контексту з результатів пошукової системи нема взагалі. Спорбуйте пошукати "бридість". Принаймні, ця форма спадає мені на думку, а інших варіантів в мене нема.

Answer (score 5):

Та ж стаття у Вікіпедії дає посилання на «більш медичні» терміни для подібного стану/явища:

- **агевзі́я** [[«Словник української мови» в 20 томах](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=191138&page=16), [«Великий тлумачний словник сучасної української мови»](//www.lingvolive.com/en-us/translate/uk-uk/%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%B7%D1%96%D1%8F)] ([ageusia](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ageusia)) — відсутня смакова чутливість;
- **гіпогевзі́я** [[«Великий тлумачний словник сучасної української мови»](//www.lingvolive.com/en-us/translate/uk-uk/%D0%B3%D1%96%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%B7%D1%96%D1%8F)] ([hypogeusia](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypogeusia)) — знижена смакова чутливість;
- **дисгевзі́я** [[«Великий тлумачний словник сучасної української мови»](//www.lingvolive.com/en-us/translate/uk-uk/%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B3%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%B7%D1%96%D1%8F)] = **парагевзі́я** [[«Великий тлумачний словник сучасної української мови»](//www.lingvolive.com/en-us/translate/uk-uk/%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%B7%D1%96%D1%8F)] ([dysgeusia=parageusia](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dysgeusia)) — неправильна смакова чутливість.

Наскільки ці терміни доречні у Вашому контексті, вирішувати Вам.

Answer (score 5):

[Штепа](//archive.org/stream/shtepa1977/shtepa1977_djvu.txt)

> Агевзія — смакобрак
>   Парагевзія *(мед)* — смакозіпсуття

Про всяк зауважу, шчо також трапяється змосковшчене нїмецьке [*агейзія*](http://medterms.com.ua/publ/medichni_termini_na_bukvu_a/agevzija/1-1-0-1171), де замість *ев* — *ей* ([пор.](/a/2629/585) *невролоґія* — *нейролоґія*).

Шчодо тямки, то *аґевзія* доречніша, оскільки сє *втрата* чи *відсутність*, а не *порушенє*.

Comment: Плюсую за «смакобрак». Ще можно щось типу «смакокриза» — якщо мова не про постійні й непереборні проблеми соматичного генезу, а про тимчасові проблеми професійних кухарів частково психологічного генезу (аналогічно до творчої кризи у письменників абощо). Але формально це все-таки ближче до гіпогевзії/дисгевзії/парагевзії (часткової втрати чи порушення), ніж до агевзії (повної втрати) — хоча в побуті таким нюансам часто уваги не приділяють і, наприклад, гіповітаміноз називають авітамінозом.